# Need CRUD operations for javers

Tags: javers

I want to archive restore the javers audit records. So I want ability to delete the records and insert them again.
Does javers repository provide delete/insert API or we use standard JPA techniques to do that ?

I have searched through the API. It has some hallowDelete API which may not serve purpose as of now.

I should have API like javers.deletebyCommitId(Long id) and javers.insertAuditData(javersEntity) etc.

Comment: Please clarify your question. `Need CRUD operations for javers` is not a question.

Comment: Javers is an auditing framework. Once the DB size increases it has to be moved to another database to save space. So need API so that the object graph data can be moved per commit-wise ? to another database so that rest of the database makes sense and the exported data should be able to import again later for studying the audit log.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to konw some data operation framework, like mybatis and hibernate, maybe jpa is more suitaable you.

I suggest you to use mybatis + mapper. they have own quick start, i think that may help you.

mybatis:  https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3

Mapper: https://github.com/abel533/Mapper

Comment: This question is related to javers auditing framework(https://javers.org/). It dpes not use MyBatis. I can use JPA but it would be better if the JaversRepository supports data operation methods. So this may sound like a feature addition request otherwise but I want to make sure I have sifted through the API enough.

Comment: I don't know much about JaVers, I am sorry that I can't help you.